# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded - LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, blockingqueue

I have implemented my own threadpool executor as below,

```
private final Queue<?> inProgressQueue;
private final Queue<?> pendingQueue;

    public ThreadPoolExecutorImpl(int corePoolSize, int maximumQueueSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit) {
            super(PoolSize, PoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
            this.maximumQueueSize = maximumQueueSize;
            this.inProgressQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
            this.pendingQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        }
```

Consumer:

```
    public class Consumer implements MessageListener {
        @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                Future<?> obj= pool.submit(new CallableClass(id, this));
        }
}
```

CallableClass:

```
    public class Callableclass extends callable{
    @Override
        public String call() {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //code
    }
   }
```

Using above code works for 2 to 3 days properly without having any issues. but after 4 days consumer, it has been stopped with below exception,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at 
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.offer(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:415)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1364)..
```

Can anyone help me regarding, why this behavior is happening? and how to resolve this issue. or shall I use Runnable instead?

Comment: `Thread.wait`?  That shouldn't actually compile, unless you have a variable somewhere called `Thread`, which would be very bad.

Comment: it might because your queues are taking too many elements. How did you consume the queues elements?  See the error occur when invoke `offer()` method.You can set a limit size for your queue, once it is reaching the limit, start dropping events or start more consumers to consume the queue

Comment: Edited to sleep(10000),,, Thanks Haifeng,

Comment: But the problem here is in offer() it couldn't able to create this portion. Node<E> node = new Node(e); since i have used LinkedBlockingQueue it will actually not a fixed size know.

Comment: your bottleneck is that adding elements to queue is faster than consuming element from queue, therefore it would eat up the memory sooner or later.  You can create a counter to store the queue size(the concurrentlinkedqueue method size() is O(N)) once the queue size reaches limit, drop the new incoming elements.  Alternatively, If drop elements are not allowed, You can start up more consumers  and make sure consuming is faster than producing

Comment: Yah, am using bounded queue by covering threadpool which will get filed first and passed to pool and get drained in same way.. How to add more consumers ? is it like two listener instances or two separate consumer app itself?

Comment: can i use arrayblockingqueue instead of linkedblockingqueue? will this help solving the GC issue?